# Inserting XML data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a xml file:

```
<root>
<application>
    <app-name>Google App</app-name>
    <group>
        <group-name>MidasGoogleAppsUsers</group-name>
        <user>
            <username>knikkhoo</username>
            <username>devendrat</username>
        </user>
    </group>
</application>
<application>
    <app-name>MySql App</app-name>
    <group>
        <group-name>MidasSQLUsers</group-name>
        <user>
            <username>knikkhoo</username>
            <username>devendrat</username>
        </user>
    </group>
</application>
<application>
    <app-name>ESNutritio</app-name>
    <group>
        <group-name>MidasNutrition</group-name>
        <user>
            <username>knikkhoo</username>
            <username>devendrat</username>
        </user>
    </group>
</application>
 </root>
```

I have a table named test_xml with strucutre in which I have stored this XML:

```
Create table test_xml
 (
  ID int,
  XMLData text
 )
```

There is another table UserAppliaction

```
 create table `test`.`UserApplication`( 
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  `ApplicationName ` varchar(100) , 
  `GroupName` varchar(100) , 
  `UserName` varchar(100) , 
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
  )
```

How can I stored this data into UserApplication table.
I am new to Mysql.

Comment: can anyone help me in this please....

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to parse the XML in SQL. Use your favorite application programming language to parse that thing, then insert the extracted data using SQL queries like this one:

```
INSERT INTO UserApplication
SET ApplicationName = ?,
    GroupName = ?,
    UserName = ?
```

In most language bindings, you can actually enter the statement like this, including the quotation marks, and then execute the statement repeatedly passing different values for these placeholders. The library will take care of properly escaping all your data. Often this approach is called “prepared statements”, since preparation and execution of the statement are to distinct steps.

Comment: Just a word of caution: Using `INSERT` with `SET` like this is MySQL specific and will not work on *any* other DBMS. The standard syntax for would be `insert into UserApplication (ApplicationName, GroupName, UserName) values (?,?,?)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: True. It's one part of MySQL syntax I really like, particularly in cases where values are more complicated expressions and I like to keep track of which one is which. But I agree that in this case, the benefit is negligible, so probably there is no reason to choose that non-portable syntax except to stay consistent with other code fragments which are not so simple. It's a matter of priority, depending on how likely a migration to another DBMS appears.